# MySql: JSON column to rows

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column in my table that is in json format. The json contains multiple records:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "person 1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "person 2"
}]
```

I want the result of my query to be like this:

```
id    |      name
1            person 1
2            person 2
```

How can I achieve this? I tried `json_extract(json_column, '$[*].id')` but it only returns all the id in an array format in one row

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236573/1316440](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236573/1316440).

Comment: this worked for me. however, I am not sure if this would still be efficient if 10 or more users trigger the stored procedure at the same time?