# MySQL: JSON to Resultset

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an archive table that has a column which contains unindexed json records. Sample:

```
[{
    "attr1": "val1",
    "attr2": "val2",
    "attr3": "val3",
    .
    .
    "attrN": "valN"
}, {
    "attr1": "val1.2",
    "attr2": "val2.2",
    "attr3": "val3.2",
    .
    .
    "attrN": "valN.2"
},...]
```

I need to create a stored procedure or function that returns the json as a resultset:

```
  attr1   |   attr2    |   attr3  | ... |  attrN
  _______________________________________________
  val1    |    val2    |   val3   | ... |  valN
  val1.2  |    val2.2  |   val2.2 | ... |  valN.2
```

I need it to return as a recordset as I will be using it for other queries in other stored procedures.

I was able to achieve this with this: [Read JSON array in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46218021/read-json-array-in-mysql/46236573#46236573)

However, I was wondering if there is another way besides creating a temporary table? I was thinking about performance and efficiency. Like, what if 20 or 50 users trigger this? Is there a better way to do this?

Note: the avarage size of the json is ~1MB

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure create a dynamic query that output the result you need, should be tested using real data to check if performance are good enough:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE jsonToCols(IN json JSON, IN target VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @j = 0;
    SET @fields = JSON_KEYS(json, "$[0]");
    SET @f_length = JSON_LENGTH(@fields);
    SET @select = "";
    WHILE @j < JSON_LENGTH(json) DO
      SET @i = 0;
      SET @select = CONCAT(@select, "SELECT ");
      WHILE @i < @f_length DO
          SET @attr_name = REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(@fields, CONCAT("$[", @i, "]")), '\"', '');
          SET @key = CONCAT('$.', @attr_name);
          SET @select = CONCAT(@select, "JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[", @j , "].", @attr_name, "') as ", @attr_name, ", ");
          SET @i = @i + 1;
      END WHILE;

      SET @select = CONCAT(LEFT(@select, length(@select)-2), " FROM ", target ," UNION ALL ");
      SET @j = @j + 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET @select = LEFT(@select, length(@select)-11);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @select;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

Dynamically created query looks like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[0].attr1') as attr1, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[0].attr2') as attr2, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[0].attr3') as attr3, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[0].attrN') as attrN 
FROM test 
UNION ALL 
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[1].attr1') as attr1, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[1].attr2') as attr2, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[1].attr3') as attr3, JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$[1].attrN') as attrN 
FROM test
```

[FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KEk3rRQqnC4M3txUDhA2C/0)